# Ruby Version Manager broke my $PATH

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, rvm

I installed RVM on OSX and now my `$PATH` variable is totally changed. I tried to change it in `.bashrc` and `.profile` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's supposed to change. Is the change causing you problems?

Comment: No, RVM works just fine. Just my custom $PATH variable is somehow overwritten.

Comment: Perhaps you should post *how* it changed unexpectedly.

Comment: This is the output of echo $PATH   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/MyHome/.rvm/bin although I set a completely different one.

Comment: Before my path also included /opt/local/bin and other stuff. Now it doesn't anymore although I include /opt/local/bin and other directories in .bashrc and .profile

Comment: The weird thing is if I call bash in bash it it reads my custom $PATH.

Comment: It just seems as if .bashrc and .profile are not loaded anymore.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - any luck resolving this??? I need to re-export my PATH each time I open a new terminal window!

Comment: @mpapis over here, I get "himBH"

Comment: I have extended my answer, try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some misuse in your RC files, have a read here: https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login

basically `.profile` should not be used as bash login RC script, there is `.bash_login` or `.bash_profile` which are better choice for it.

to fix your profile files you need to run:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

and restart computer - yes restart the machine, it's only a minute on mac

Comment: @Tass not always, .profile is sourced by X server, and not all of them restart when you relogin.

Comment: This command was without any effect on my machine. 
For me this is a huge RVM Bug.

Comment: @RobertReiz I do not understand your problem, either fill in a bug report for RVM or read more on how RVM works - especially for changing current working Ruby, there would be no `rvm use` without changing environment variables.

Comment: @mpapis I have read more on how RVM works. And in the mean while I could repair my PATH. I like RVM and I don't want to miss it. It is a great tool. BUT .. :-) .. the installation is a mess. There is room for improvements. For me it is a No-Go that after the default installation the PATH is messed up and some of my used commands just dont't work anymore. I had this issue already several times and I am not the only one.

Comment: @RobertReiz there is a ticket that my help you, also there are some things that can not be fixed in RVM1 - we have plan to make this a lot better in RVM2, but this will take time to complete.

Comment: @mpapis I am happy to hear that. Looking forward to RVM2 :-)

Comment: I have the same problem.  The suggested solution did not work.  Also https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/#shell_login seems to no longer exist.  RVM install seems to just blat a standard OS X install.  People should we warned about this beforehand, rather than have to go rummaging around for a solution when its too late.  Can you please supply a link to the ticket you mentioned above?

Comment: I've been using .profile for wrong stuff for many years. Thanks rvm for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, this solution still leaves me with a PATH that I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when I had an rvm binary in /opt/local/bin (a macport called 'rsync vault manager').  After uninstalling that, rvm stopped removing /opt/local/bin from my path.